# Computing degree of local bridge in R igraph

Tags: r, distance, igraph

I am computing the degree of a local bridge: the geodesic distance between adjacent nodes i and j if the i-j edge were removed (Granovetter 1973).

I can do it by looping over the edges:

```
library(igraph)
G <- sample_smallworld(1, 10, 2, 0.05)  #A random graph
for (edge in 1:gsize(G)) {                           #For each edge...
  ends <- ends(G, edge)                              #...get ends
  subgraph <- delete.edges(G, edge)                  #...delete edge
  distance <- distances(subgraph, ends[1], ends[2])  #...get distance
  E(G)$bridge[edge] <- distance                      #...update attribute
}
```

This works, but is impractically slow for large graphs. Any suggestions on making it more efficient?

Comment: Instead of deleting the edge, temporarily set its weight to infinity. You don't need to store the weight as an edge attribute, just create a vector of all-ones, then set the element corresponding to the edge of interest to `Inf`, then do  weighted shortest path calculation. This should be less expensive than deleting the edge.

Answer (score 1):

@Szabolcs gave a great solution. I'm posting it here to show the code and timing:

```
library(igraph)
G <- erdos.renyi.game(1000, .01)

system.time(
for (edge in 1:gsize(G)) {                           #For each edge...
  ends <- ends(G, edge)                              #...get ends
  subgraph <- delete.edges(G, edge)                  #...delete edge
  distance <- distances(subgraph, ends[1], ends[2])  #...get new distance
  E(G)$bridge[edge] <- distance                      #...update attribute
}
)
   user  system elapsed 
  3.576   0.288   3.861 

system.time(
for (edge in 1:gsize(G)) {                      #For each edge...
  w <- rep(1,gsize(G))                          #Vector of 1s
  w[edge] <- Inf                                #Selected edge's weight is Inf
  ends <- ends(G, edge)                         #...get ends
  distance <- distances(G, ends[1], ends[2], weights = w)  #...get weighted distance using w
  E(G)$bridge2[edge] <- distance                #...update attribute
}
)
   user  system elapsed 
  1.710   0.214   1.924 

all.equal(E(G)$bridge, E(G)$bridge2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hm, only 2x speedup for this large graph is a bit disappointing though. Thanks for benchmarking! One issue here is that weighted shorted path calculations are quite a bit slower than unweighted ones. Another is that each call to `distances()` involves a fixed overhead. This could definitely be sped up more if it's implemented directly in the C core of igraph. However, I'm not sure how widely used this concept of "bridge span" of "bridge degree" is . It is the first time I encounter it.

Comment: If you think that this is a commonly used concept in your field and that there would be wider demand for a faster implementation, feel free to [write up a feature request](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/new/choose), including references and information about the use of this concept. Note that igraph already has an implementation of the k shortest paths problem, which is related but not identical. This is not exposed in R/igraph yet. It makes it possible to find not the shortest, but the second shortest path. In unweighted graphs this is the same as what you're looking for.

Comment: @szabolcs The k_shortest_path function would cover my application. It's true that the concept of "bridge degree" is not common. However, it is the definition of a bridge used by Granovetter in his highly-cited 1973 "Strength of Weak Ties" paper, so I'm surprised it isn't more common.